# How to use JScript Promises in an MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert2

I am currently using [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) in my **MVC project** and it works fine. However, I need to add some radio buttons to it. This feature seems to be part of [SweetAlert Version 2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2).

Now if I do the following **without the word await**:

```
   function SampleCode() {
        var formValues = await swal.fire({
            title: 'Multiple inputs',
            html:
                '<input id="swal-input1">' +
                '<input type="checkbox" id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
                ];
            }
        });

        //Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(formValues));
    }
```

Then the dialog does pop up. But if I uncomment the second SweetAlert, of course it won't work as I need to make a use of promises. How do I do that in the above function which is in a .cshtml file in an MVC project? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The fact it's in a cshtml file is irrelevant. You can still use all JavaScript features. Is that really what you're asking about, or are you actually just asking about somehow using Promises in this code?

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for the reply. Actually both are my questions. Good to know I can use all features in cshtml. But, when i add await, I get the red underline and the editor doesn't recognize it. Also I don't know how to get promises in there either.

Comment: If you're talking about visual studio as the editor, ignore it, the JavaScript intellisense is pretty useless. Much better to debug it using your browser's Developer Tools. And if you're intending to use await then (assuming swal.fire() returns a promise) the I think you're already doing the right thing probably. Give it a try.

Comment: I had already tried. The await keyword is not recognized and I was getting an error about. I believe, I might have to import some library or something. This should allow to use await in jscript as well as .then(). But don't know how.

Comment: Exactly what error do you get? Is the error generated by visual studio, or by your browser? And what browser (and version) are you testing with?

Comment: P.S. In hindsight I think you might be right that "await" is not the way to go. Perhaps this demo https://jsfiddle.net/juanma/46pu4njb/ will help you get an idea of what to do .

Comment: And I made an even simpler version, based more on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/5vc6rfgq/

Comment: Alternatively, from the [documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration) (the section which says _"Multiple inputs aren't supported, you can achieve them by using html and preConfirm parameters..."_), here's a CodePen showing something closer to what I think you might be trying to do. Looks like you forgot to declare the outer function as being async, which probably is the reason for your error: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyNYep?&editable=true

Comment: @ADyson, thank you so much for your help. I have actually removed the references to SweetAlert2 and decided to use the bootstrap modal dialog. However, I am very keen to see if I can get the promises working in the JScript. So I have bookmarked this  question and will comeback to it over next few days or might be weeks. But I'll be back. :)

Comment: @ADyson, got a chance to try this again. It does work. Just added the async/await in the cshtml, it did work as you mentioned. It gives the red underlining, but you are right the VS editor is not geared for JSCript. Thank you very much for your help. If you post your answer, I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration) (the section which says "Multiple inputs aren't supported, you can achieve them by using html and preConfirm parameters..."), here's a CodePen showing something closer to what I think you might be trying to do. Looks like you forgot to declare the outer function as being async, which probably is the reason for your error: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyNYep?&editable=true

For reference, the JavaScript needs to look like this:

```
(async function getFormValues () {
const {value: formValues} = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Multiple inputs',
  html:
    '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input">' +
    '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
  focusConfirm: false,
  preConfirm: () => {
    return [
      document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
      document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
    ]
  }
})

if (formValues) {
  Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(formValues))
}
})()
```